# Manipulating Matched values in Regex C#

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, text, richtextbox

I have read a text file and matched the data I am interested in. My question is, what is the best way to manipulate the data I have matched?
The code I am reading the text file with is.

```
 OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
       dialog.Filter =
          "All files (*.*)|*.*";
       //dialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
       dialog.Title = "Select a text file";

       if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
       {
           string fname = dialog.FileName; // selected file
           label1.Text = fname;
           if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(richTextBox1.Text))
           {
               var matches1 = Regex.Matches(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fname), @"L10 P\d\d\d R \S\S\S\S\S\S\S")
          .Cast<Match>()
          .Select(m => m.Value)
          .ToList();

               richTextBox1.Lines = matches1.ToArray();
           }
```

The result now looks like:

```
L10 P015 R +4.9025
```

and I need it to look like this:

```
#2015=4.9025
```

`L10` is excluded, `P015` turns into `#2015`, `R` and `+` turn into `=`, and the number stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capturing groups:

- First change your regex to:

  ```
  L10 P(?<key>\d{3}) R \S(?<val>\S{6})
  ```

  The `(?<name>`...`)` syntax lets you declare a named capturing group. You can later retrieve the value that was matched by this group.
- Next, when you have a match object, you can extract the matching group contents with `match.Groups["key"].Value` and `match.Groups["val"].Value`, like that:

  ```
  .Select(m => string.Format("#2{0}={1}", m.Groups["key"].Value, m.Groups["val"].Value))
  ```

Comment: Works Great!! Thanks.

Comment: If I wanted to add 2000 to the 15, could this be done using basically the same method? The reason I ask is that I have another format that uses 2200 instead of 2000. And if my P015 end up being P125 then my result would need to be 2325.

Comment: @user2139891 sure: `string.Format("#{0}={1}", int.Parse(m.Groups["key"].Value) + 2000, m.Groups["val"].Value)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fname), @"L10 P\d\d\d R \S\S\S\S\S\S\S")
      .Cast<Match>()
      .Select(m => m.Value)
      .ToList();

string num1 = "2" + matches[1].Substring(1); // "2" + "015"
string num2 = matches[3].Substring(1); // "4.9025"

string finalValue = "#" + num1 + "=" + num2; // "#2015=4.9025"
richTextBox1.Text = finalValue;
```

I believe that this should work, based on your single example.

This assumes that we are simply *always* ignoring the first character of the `P015` item and the first character of the `+4.9025` item.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply split the receiving stream, your rules are basic and there is no need for regexes.

```
    string receivingStream = "L10 P015 R +4.9025";
    string[] tokens = receivingStream.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
```

- tokens[0] == L10
- tokens[1] == Date
- tokens[2] == R
- tokens[3] == Number

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using `Regex.Replace` to mutate the string once instead of going through all of this matching.  You'll want to add grouping to the regex, and use substitutions in the replacement string.

see:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx